# Django REST API Multiple Records Same Category

Tags: python, django, rest

There is a problem with Django Rest API , i have a 2 records in my creators table.
first records have category "gaming" and the second record have category "Education" all is ok for now , but when i add Thirds record with Category "Education"(same category of first record ) then i got the error when i call all records of That Category(gaming).

**i want the multiple records of same category**

**model.py**

```
class Creators(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subscriber = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    socialLinks = models.TextField(max_length=2000)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class CreatorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Creators
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatorsList(APIView):

    def get(self,request,category):
        creator = Creators.objects.get(category=category)
        serializer = CreatorsSerializer(creator)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self):
        pass
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^creators/(?P<category>\w+)/$', views.CreatorsList.as_view()),
```

when i run **example.com/creators/Gaming/** then it gives me perfect output(for now i just have 2 records)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "channel1",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJbPGzawDH1njbqV-D5HqKw",
    "subscriber": 2000,
    "country": "PK",
    "email": "ishaq@gmail.com",
    "description": "ddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnknd",
    "category": "Gaming",
    "socialLinks": "ddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnkndddkndkndkdknkdnknd"
}
```

but when i added third records of same category (Gaming) the error shows

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /creators/Education/
get() returned more than one Creators -- it returned 2!
```

i also added many=True in  views.py but nothing happens even the category of 1 records also not working in this case

```
class CreatorsList(APIView):

    def get(self,request,category):
        creator = Creators.objects.get(category=category,many=True)
        serializer = CreatorsSerializer(creator)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Change `get` to `filter`

Comment: wow its working :) thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You need to use filter instead of get in this line

```
creator = Creators.objects.get(category=category)
```

the method get() expect to return only one record and give this error if it returns more. Then the correct is :

```
creator = Creators.objects.filter(category=category)
```